# PostgreSql pasar un array como argumento en un WHERE NOT a través de una función

Tags: postgresql

Tengo una función sql que crea una vista materializada:

```
CREATE FUNCTION reports_mt_views(exclude_ids int[]) RETURNS void AS 
$BODY$
BEGIN
    EXECUTE 'CREATE MATERIALIZED VIEW tx_materialized AS
        SELECT tx.transaccion_id AS tx_transaccion_id,
        ...
        WHERE  creation_date > (current_date - interval '' ' || $2 || ' month '')
        AND (account_id <> ALL (' || exclude_ids || '))'
RETURN;
END;
$BODY$ LANGUAGE plpgsql STRICT;
```

También lo he intentado de la siguiente manera:

```
AND account_id NOT IN ' || exclude_ids || ')'
```

Pero esto no funciona cuando ejecuto:

```
SELECT reports_mt_views(ARRAY [1,2,8,538524]);
```

Obtengo este error:

```
ERROR:  operator does not exist: text || integer[]
LINE 171:     AND (account_id <> ALL (' || exclude_ids || '))'
                                         ^
HINT:  No operator matches the given name and argument type(s). You might need to add explicit type casts.
```

No hay problema con el arreglo de por sí. Yo probé con un FOR loop y funciona. Pero al pasarlo como condición no lo hace. ¿Qué puedo estar haciendo mal?

Comment: que verison de postgres?

Comment: estoy usando la 9.6

Comment: Te dejo un ejemplo, https://www.postgresql.org/message-id/6d8daee30607181024w74cf4673gf2f55066219dc21%40mail.gmail.com

Comment: Basicamente define el parametro como INT[] y usa un alias para $1

Answer (score 0, accepted):

La solución es hacer una concatenación del arreglo como texto para que pueda ser leída por la clausula *where not in*.

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION pps.reports_mt_views(exclude_ids integer[])
...
DECLARE
    in_accounts ALIAS FOR $1;
    out_accounts  TEXT;
BEGIN
    out_accounts := in_accounts;
    out_accounts := trim(leading '{' FROM out_accounts);
    out_accounts := trim(trailing '}' FROM out_accounts);
```

Así, ya se puede utilizar de la siguiente manera:

```
WHERE (orden.cuenta_id NOT IN (' || out_accounts || '))
```